# Obtain using definition from templated class

Tags: c++, c++14

Given the following classes:

```cpp
// Some random class
class A { };

// A templated class with a using value in it.
template<class TYPE_B> 
class B {
  public:
    using TYPE = TYPE_B;
};
```

Next we use these two classes in class C. But if we are using B as the template parameter we would like to obtain the TYPE defined in it.

```cpp
template<class TYPE_C>
class C {
    // A check to see if we have a class of type B 
    static constexpr bool IS_B = std::is_same<B<int32_t>, TYPE_C>::value ||
                                 std::is_same<B<int64_t>, TYPE_C>::value;

  public:
    // This is what not works. How to get B::TYPE here?
    using TYPE = std::conditional<IS_B, TYPE_C::TYPE, TYPE_C>;
};
```

Class C would we used like:

```cpp
C<A> ca;
C<B<int32_t>> cb32;
C<B<int64_t>> cb64;
```

I am compiling this in GCC. My fear what I would like not have to do is to use the std::is_same statement for each type used with B. Put that in the std::conditional. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: What is `DATA_TYPE`? You're most likely missing a `typename` keyword prior before `DATA_TYPE::TYPE`.

Comment: Sorry copy past fault. I will modify the code.

Comment: Then you do need `typename TYPE_C::TYPE`. The duplicate will tell you why. I don't know which compiler you're  using but you should carefully read the error messages because gcc, clang and MSVC all tell you what to do in this case, see https://godbolt.org/z/YbbedzK61.

Comment: @holt will have to look more closely at the awnser but first results are not good. `using TYPE = std::conditional<IS_B, typename TYPE_C::TYPE, TYPE_C>;` does not build. Will let you know what I find later.

Comment: I removed the duplicate, Your question is slightly different, you need to delay the `::TYPE` in a different template. There are most likely duplicate on SO for this.

Comment: Probably, I did look but did not find the proper search term to get it.
It appears also that std::conditional does not work with using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues in your code:

1. You are missing a `typename` before `TYPE_C::TYPE`. Since `TYPE_C::TYPE` is a dependent name, you need to use `typename` to tell the compiler that you are looking for a type.
2. You cannot use `TYPE_C::TYPE` ins the `std::conditional`<sup>1</sup> expression because when `TYPE_C` is not `B<>`, that expression is invalid, but will still be evaluated.

One simple solution is to use an intermediate template to access the type, using template specialization, e.g.

```cpp
template <class T>
struct get_C_type {
    using type = T;
};

template <class T>
struct get_C_type<B<T>> {
    using type = T;
};

template<class TYPE_C>
class C {
public:
    // you still need a typename here
    using TYPE = typename get_C_type<TYPE_C>::type;
};
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> You probably want to use `std::conditional_t` or `std::conditional<>::type` here.</sub>